# How to initialize an interface object in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface

To pass data frm a `Fragment` to the `main Activity`, I created an `Interface` which will be instantiated in the `Fragment` and implemented in the `Main Activity`. actualy, I understand how to do it and how the Interface works, but what I could not understand is the below code which something like initialising the interface object.

My Question is, why the Interface object is initially set to `=(ItemVisibilityPasser) activity`?

**Code**

```
public void onAttach(android.app.Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    visibilityPasser = (ItemVisibilityPasser) activity;
};
```

Comment: Because the android.app.Activity does not implement your interface. here you should probably check with instanceof operator to see if your fragment is really hosted in Activity which implements needed interface

Comment: @TomislavNovoselec ok, now i want to initialize an object of an interface in an activity not a fragment, where and how should i initialise it.? should i do that in onCreate() { interfaceObj = ???? }

Comment: Since I have no idea what that object is supposed to do, I can't give you an exact answer.

Comment: @TomislavNovoselec it is an obj of "Toggleinterface", when an item in the list View in the NavDearwe is pressed, i just call obj.onMQTTConnectionPressed(), and the fragment will implement this interface